# How do I convert my google maps application into a google earth application?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-earth-plugin

On maps.google.com you can see a brilliant example on how a google maps application can suddenly turn into a google earth application smoothly.

I'm developing a google maps application, working with API version 3. I read the following line in the Google Earth API summary

> If you have an existing Maps API site,
>   you can 3D-enable your page with as
>   little as one line of code.

But I have searched for hours without finding any clue how to enable 3D in my application. I've built my application on the google.maps.Map constructor and included the google mas API from this url: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js

Does anyone know what I'm talking about and/or know how to enable 3D in a google maps application in 1 line?

Codemonkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the Google Earth instance to your map, simply add the `G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP` to your map with `GMap2.addMapType()`.

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),{ size: new GSize(640,480) } );
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(42.366662,-71.106262), 11);

// Enable the Earth map type
map.addMapType(G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP);

var mapControl = new GMapTypeControl();
map.addControl(mapControl);
map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP);
```

Here is the information on Integrating v2 of the maps Api with the Google Earth Plugin
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Earth

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer by Fraser is perfect for V2 of the Maps API.  However it's strongly recommended to use V3 since V2 has been deprecated.

To get similar functionality in V3 you can use the utility library at http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/ -- simply include the javascript library, and then in your code instantiate the Earth layer for your map:

```
var googleEarth = new GoogleEarth(map);
```

Comment: I didn't think that the GE api was available in v3 of maps. Thanks for the heads up on the utility lib!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Google means using KML(KMZ) files?
This language supports by Googgle Earth and Google Map.
I can make mistake, but it link is helpful - http://sketchup.wikia.com/wiki/KML

Comment: The quote from their Google Earth API says quite clearly that if I have a Maps API site, 1 line of code can turn it into a 3D map, so I'm going to keep my hopes up that that's possible

Comment: How does it make sense that v2 has features v3 is not capable of? Just out of curiosity

Comment: epitaph: Say my application is v2, how would I make a google earth application out of it by adding 1 line?