# Earth in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I recently came by this website: http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/earthview.html

"Earth view in Google Maps"

Does this mean, I use the usual Google Maps APIs (V3) to manage the map while being able to render in Earth view? More explanation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question and the accepted answer:

- [How do I convert my google maps application into a google earth application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345375/how-do-i-convert-my-google-maps-application-into-a-google-earth-application)

Per that answer, you can find additional detail here:

- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Earth

Answer (score 0):

The EarthView link is about taking advantage of the Google Earth plugin at maps.google.com, and not related to enabling it for your own site.

The recommended strategy for integrating the plugin into your own mashup is to use the utility library at http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/